# Assert That "expect" Called X Times in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, ava

How can I fail the test if `expect` was not called at all? Or even better, when it was not called X times?

For example:

```
it('should fail', () => {
    if (1 === 2) {
        expect(1).toEqual(1)
    }
}
```

In other words, what is the equivalent of `ava`-`t.plan` in `Jest`?

Comment: I think this is about JavaScript. The Java tag is inappropriate here.

Comment: great thanks. why down voting because of typo ?

Comment: Because it confuses the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`expect.hasAssertions()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#expecthasassertions) to ensure an assertion was made:

```
it('made an assertion', () => {
    expect.hasAssertions();
    if (1 === 2) {
        expect(1).toEqual(1)
    }
}
```

In this case, the test would fail because `expect` is never called.

You can also use [`expect.assertions(...)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#expectassertionsnumber) to ensure a specific number of assertions were made in your test. This test will pass:

```
it('made 2 assertions', () => {
    expect.assertions(2);
    expect(1).toEqual(1);
    expect(2).toEqual(2);
}
```

See the Jest documentation on [`expect`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html) for more information.